# What is the difference between Google Closure and AngularJS approaches of unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, google-closure

I just received a project of a medium size which contains a lot of Closure unit tests. I'm going to rewrite the GUI part in AngularJS. Regarding this I have some questions:

1. Is it fine to test AngularJS with Closure tests?
2. What benefits will I have from rewriting Closure tests to AngularJS? Is it worth rewriting?

I'm new to both Closure and Angular, please forgive me if I misused some terms.

Comment: It should work, a few things i would take into consideration, dependent on how the code was written it might rely on closures dependency management system and as you convert you will start loosing that. SO as you convert, start writing new tests as well.